# Query multiple pages on frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code, but it is not going after the first request:

```
<?php $thePostIdArray = array( '2', '4', '5'); ?>
        <?php $limit = 4; ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>
        <?php if ( $counter < $limit+1): ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; ?>
            <?php $queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>
            <?php $title =$queried_post->post_title; ?>
            <?php $content = $queried_post->post_content; ?>
            <h2><span><?php echo $title ?></span></h2>
            <?php echo $content; ?> </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It is only out putting the first page(2) of the request even though the footer and the sidebar are been queried. I eliminate the sidebar and the footer, but no change so the problem is not from them.
Any help here will be appreciated. By the way I am using the lasted wordpress

Comment: this question should be migrated on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm too concentrated on the syntax to understand the code...

Comment: This is the way I write when debugging code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need The Loop since you know the IDs of the posts (or pages).

```
<?php 
$thePostIdArray = array( '2', '4', '5');
foreach ($thePostIdArray as $thePostId):
    $thePost = get_post($thePostId);
    <?php if (!empty ($thePost)): ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $thePostId; ?>">
            <?php $title =$thePost->post_title; ?>
            <?php $content = $thePost->post_content; ?>
            <h2><span><?php echo title ?></span></h2>
            <?php echo $content; ?> </div>
        <?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
```